# Variable doesn't update after having event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot update the value for userPickColor for some reason, it is always undefined. But I try to console.log inside the functions and my values are actually changing. But for some reasons, once I call it outside the function, it doesn't update at all.
I'm still new to Javascript so Please Help me

Here is my code:

```
 var white = document.getElementById("white");
 var black = document.getElementById("black");
 var userPickColor;

 white.addEventListener("click", whiteshirt);
 black.addEventListener("click", blackshirt);

 function whiteshirt(){
   userPickColor= "white";
 }

function blackshirt(){
  userPickColor= "black";
}

ShirtDescrp.innerHTML = userPickColor;
```

Comment: The value of the variable changes on every click, but the text in the HTML doesn't change. You've to put the last line in the event handler functions too.

Comment: I try that one and still doesn't work. Is there another way for this?

Comment: [No](https://jsfiddle.net/cmnkaLj9/)?

Comment: @Teemu-callmewhateveryouwant I did that and it works properly. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, you need to place the line that updates the `.innerHTML` inside of the callback functions so that after the variable has been updated, you can update the page with the most current variable value as well.

But, taking this one step further... There is a common coding methodology called DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) and you've got two callback functions that largely do the same thing. The only difference is the actual text that gets set. Those two functions run when one of two elements on your page get clicked and those two elements have the text you want to use as their `id`s. We could easily combine the two callbacks into just one like this:

```js
var ShirtDescrp = document.getElementById("des");

// There's nothing wrong with variables if they help you read the code
// more easily, but if you won't be using the value they store more than
// once, they don't really add much.
document.getElementById("white").addEventListener("click", changeColor);
document.getElementById("black").addEventListener("click", changeColor);

function changeColor() { 
  // No variable needed. Just set the text to the id of the element that got clicked
  // "this" here refers to the object that initiated the call for the current function
  // which will be one of the two buttons.
  ShirtDescrp.innerHTML = this.id;
}
```

```html
<button id="white">white</button>
<button id="black">black</button>

<p id="des"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, I was taking consideration about the method DRY for coding that's why I did not try to put the userPickColor inside the function in the first place. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

you have to put `ShirtDescrp.innerHTML = userPickColor;` inside your event listener as well since you change the variable but you didn't tell the dom to update the content

Answer (score 0):

You should update the DOM same as the variable:

```js
var white = document.getElementById("white");
var black = document.getElementById("black");
var ShirtDescrp = document.getElementById("des");
var userPickColor = null;

white.addEventListener("click", whiteshirt);
black.addEventListener("click", blackshirt);

function whiteshirt() {

  userPickColor = "white";
  ShirtDescrp.innerHTML = userPickColor;
}

function blackshirt() {
  userPickColor = "black";
  ShirtDescrp.innerHTML = userPickColor;
}
```

```html
<button id="white">white</button>
<button id="black">black</button>

<p id="des"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already got your answer... Change doesn't affect as update is not happening inside event listener. This is just a recommendation how I would do it (especially if i had more color options):

```
  <p id="color-name">none</p>

  <div class="color-buttons">
    <button id="white">White</button>
    <button id="black">Black</button>
    <button id="orange">Orange</button>
    <button id="blue">Blue</button>
    <button id="green">Green</button>
    <button id="red">Red</button>
  </div>
```

JavaScript like:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".color-buttons button");
var color_name = document.getElementById("color-name");

buttons.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    color_name.style.background=this.id;
    color_name.innerHTML=this.id;
  });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5nag6kbs/) to play around.

I would also probably generate those buttons dynamically as well. And also wouldn't use `id` to store color but i would use something else like `data-color='red'` for example.